# What is the general binomial formula for the probability of getting at least N 6's from rolling M number of dice

Tags: probability

This is the question for Balazs Rau or others who can also help.
Example:
I roll M number of six-sided dice at once.

1. What is the formula for the probabilty, P(ANS), of getting at least $N$ number of $6$'s?
2. What is the formula for getting all bad outcomes (less than $N$ number of $6$'s occurrences)?
3. What is the formula for getting all good outcomes (At least $N$ number of $6$'s occurrences)?

Note: For questions 2 and 3 above, I don't mean probability; I mean the count of good/bad outcomes.

Total outcomes is of course $6^M$

====================================================

Comment: Total outcomes is 6^M.

Comment: In 2) you characterize 'all bad outcomes' by 'no occurrence of $N$ $6$'s'. Are you sure? I would expect 'no occurence of $6$'s' wich is associated to the word 'all'. In 3) I would expect a characterisation like 'occurence of $M$ $6$'s' on the same grounds. Also have a look at the comment of kmitov. There are $6^M$ possible outcomes.

Comment: Noted: Total outcomes has been corrected to $6^M$ instead of $6^N$.
No occurrence of N 6's means less than N 6's appeared after rolling the M number of dice. I hope this help to clarify

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting at least $N$ number of $6$'s is:
$$P(x\ge N)=\Sigma_{x=N}^{M}\binom{M}{x}(\frac{1}{6})^x(\frac{1}{6})^{(M-x)}$$

since the probabilty of getting exactly $m$ favorable events $p$ out of $m$ trials is $$\binom{m}{n}p^xp^{(m-n)}$$so we sum over all these probabilities when $m$ is at least $N$.

The probability of getting all good outcomes is $$(\frac{1}{6})^M$$ and it complement is  the probabilty of all events being bad.

Comment: The events 'all bad' and 'all good' are (in most cases) not complements. There is the possibility of 'some bad and some good'.

Comment: I think the formula for the probability of getting at least N number of 6's may not be right as you have NOT taken the bad outcomes (5/6) into consideration.

Comment: When I said the events of 'all bad outcomes' I mean all the outcomes less than N number of 6's occurrences; and 'all good outcomes' I mean all the outcomes with at least N number of 6's occurrences; in this case they should be complements.

So getting all good outcomes I don't mean getting exactly all N numbers of 6's; Any greater than N number of 6's to M number of 6's are also considered as good outcomes. 

For questions 2 and 3 above, I don't mean probability answer; I mean the count of good/bad outcomes as just defined.